# How to update sandbox with new releases

Tags: sandbox, pre-release

I was told there was a way to update the sandboxes with the new release prior to it being deployed to production.  But, when I look at trust.salesforce.com, the major release schedule shows production updating before test.  Since I am new to Saleforce, I'm just trying to get a feel for the upgrade process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to each Salesforce release users with the profile of system administrator receive email instructions to enable the Sandbox preview for that release. Here are those instructions for the Winter '14 release:

http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2013/08/winter-14-sandbox-preview-instructions.html

Only sandboxes on CS3, CS4, CS5, CS7, CS9, CS11, CS12, CS13, CS14, CS15, CS17 are already upgraded. If you do not already have a sandbox on one of these Salesforce servers, you will have to wait until October 12.